# On Red Hat Linux how do you determine what edition of Sybase SQL Anywhere?

Tags: linux, sybase

RHEL 6.3
Sybase SQL Anywhere 12

When running Sybase SQL Anywhere, how, from the OS command line, can you determine what 'edition' (not version) of the database you are running (Developer, Standard, Educational, Advanced, etc.)?

Hint: This may be available from the license file but what if you do not have the privileges to view the license file?  There must be an executable or library that signifies which edition of the database is running/installed, but what would that be?

Answer (score 2):

You could retrieve that information from inside the database.

```
SELECT PROPERTY ('ProductName')  --Returns the name of the software
SELECT PROPERTY ('ProductVersion')  --Returns the version of the software being run.
```

It may also be available using the [`dblic` utility](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbadmin/dblic.html), but that would likely require priviledges to the licesne file.

Besides those options, I don't know if there are binary/library differences which would give it away.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I found your response useful.  However one of the issues is that I can't access the database because the connection limit has been exceeded and the dba account is already in use.  I am trying to determine if possibly the issue is that the edition is an evaluation or developer edition which has a limit of only 10 connections.  I seem to have read that one could look for a file -- dbserv.so or dbdev.so, something like that -- on the OS and thereby determine the edition.  I am assisting the DBA who is a newbie and I can not get the DBA account for obvious reasons.

Comment: My SQLAnywhere installation is on my laptop at home, so I can't check ATM.  I'll try to take a look, and see if that is the case.